# Can standard excel errors be trapped at input of a custom VBA function?

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to know if there’s any way in Excel VBA custom function to recognize that the input data is one of the standard Excel errors e.g. #DIV/0!

Say I have a very simple Excel VBA Custom function as Myadd

```
Function Myadd(a, b)
   Myadd = a + b
End Function
```

In Excel sheet cell A3 I enter say `=Myadd(A1,A2)`
This obviously works fine as long as A1 & A2 are numeric. But if I create a standard excel error in A1, e.g. `=1/0` then it results into #DIV/0! in A1 and A1 is input to Myadd function. Since there's no numeric input, Myadd results into #VALUE!.

I can use Isnumeric function in VBA but it would be specific to this example. However generally is there any way for me to know that input to the custom function is in fact a cell containing one of the error codes like #DIV/0! or #VALUE! etc.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For errors use **`IsError()`** (`#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, #NULL!`)

To check that parameters contain a single cell use `TypeName(a) = "Range"` and `CountLarge > 1`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyAdd(ByVal a As Variant, ByVal b As Variant) As Long

    If TypeName(a) = "Range" Then If a.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Set a = a.Cells(1)
    If TypeName(b) = "Range" Then If b.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Set b = b.Cells(1)

    If IsError(a) Then
        a = 0
    Else
        a = IIf(Not IsNumeric(Val(a)), 0, Val(a))
    End If

    If IsError(b) Then
        b = 0
    Else
        b = IIf(Not IsNumeric(Val(b)), 0, Val(b))
    End If

    MyAdd = a + b
End Function
```

---

Comment: Thank you. Above code helped. Basically I was not aware of IsError function. Now I can traps the excel errors at input itself in VBA function. One thing (though I am not sure why) is that when input is error the code gives Run time error 13 Type Mismatch at 'Not IsNumeric(Val(a))'  It has issue with Val(a) it seems when a is error. Runtime error does not occur if I remove Val and just put 'Not IsNumeric(a)' I am not sure why is it so.

Comment: Val(a) extracts the number from a string, if the string starts with digits - from "123abc" will extract "123". So if you type just "test" it will be replaced with 0. When you get the Runtime error 13 is the value of a  = #DIV/0! ?